# javascript checking for function and giving output if it exists

Tags: javascript

I need a script that checks if a function is on the page and, if it is, it calls a function and if not it calls a different function. I also need the script to keep being entered automatically on a webpage.

This is what I thought of:

```
if(Examplefunction) 
  difffunction();
else
  otherfunction();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be careful with checking for names that may have not been defined in JavaScript. Referencing a name that is not defined will yield an error:

```
> if (Examplefunction) console.log('exists'); else console.log('???')
ReferenceError: Examplefunction is not defined
```

Checking a name with `typeof`, however, *is* safe, whether that name has been defined or not. Therefore, to check if a variable has been defined to a truthy value, you should use:

```
if (typeof Examplefunction != 'undefined' && Examplefunction)
  difffunction();
else
  otherfuunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as:

```
if(funcNameHere){
  funcNameHere(); // executes function
  console.log('function exists');
}
else{
  someOtherFunction(); // you can always execute another function
  console.log("function doesn't exist");
}
```

Want to make a function that does it all:

```
function funcSwitch(func1, func2){
  var exc = func1 ? func1 : func2;
  exc();  
}
// check to see if `firstFunction` exists then call - or call `secondFunction`
fucSwitch(firstFunction, secondFunction);
```

Of course, it won't work if you don't pass a variable that is a function. A function name is basically a variable that gets executed with `()` in JavaScript. If you're used to PHP then the function name would have to be a String. It's a variable in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof name === 'function') {
    name();
}
else {
    // do whatever
}
```

Note this is terrible design. You can't check how many arguments it expects, for instance.